# How to change the "i" circle color (tittle color)

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring

Is anyway to change the tittle color of the "i" character in swift?

I want to change the color of the circle of the "i" to orange but I can't find how to do that.

For example, I have this:

[image: click]

and I want to do this:

[image: click orange circle]

I want to do that with `NSAttributedString` but I can't find anything.

The "tittle" is the circle of the "i" character, when I search on the internet how to change that color, I only get result to change the `UINavigationBar` title

Comment: Do you mean constructing an attributed string where the "i" in "Click" has another color than the rest?

Comment: @Sajjon No, I want to change the color of the circle of the "i" like the "i" of the image

Comment: I am fairly sure that is impossible using NSAttributedString. Or on string basis at all. I think you need an image for that.

Comment: @Sajjon that's what I thought but I don't use an image because that word is from a logo and that logo is inside a paragraph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using some Unicode tricks, you can (sort of) do it. The trick is the [combining dot above](http://unicode-table.com/en/0307/) character (`U+0307`). Make it a different color and adjust its baseline to completely overlap the dot on the i:

```
let attributes = [
    NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(50, weight: UIFontWeightHeavy)
]
let dotAttributes = [
    NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(60, weight: UIFontWeightHeavy),
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor(),
    NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName: -15
]

let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "cli\u{307}ck", attributes: attributes)
attributedString.setAttributes(dotAttributes, range: NSMakeRange(3, 1))

textLabel.attributedText = attributedString
```

Result:

[image]

The downside is that you have to experiment with the font size and baseline offset in `dotAttributes` to get it to play nice with your regular text - there's no universal rule for them.

Comment: Thank you very much it works perfectly !